# Is LINQ's Enumerable.Take method a good equivalent of SQL's TOP in terms of speed?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to query in a table of almost 1 million entries, but the interesting part is only the top 500.

I wonder if using the Take() method in the end of the query line is the best alternative in terms of speed (and memory) optimization, or it's the same thing of just doing the whole query and then taking the top elements.

Comment: Take a look at the SQL generated form the given LINQ query.  That will give you your answer.  (It'll depend on context.  The query provider may or may not be able to translate it into a `Top` call depending on how it's used.)

Comment: Your first assumption is right

Comment: @Alireza except for the bit where it isn't

Comment: @Servy I didn't knew I could check the SQL generated through the Log property of DataContext. This will help me in the future. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run Enumerable.Take, then you are using linq-to-objects - and yes it will run the entire query and filter at the client. This will be unnecessarily expensive.

Which is why you shouldn't be doing that. You should be using Queryable.Take - then it will *do the right thing*, and page at the database.

If you use:

```
var page = query.Take(count)
```

(etc) it will get it right automatically.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your query provider. If you use linq to entities or linq to sql, the linq query will be translated to sql - in other words, it's equivalent to using sql directly.

Usually when using linq in context of databases, that's what you will do.